# Why is the lambda function not copying out the struct?

Tags: c++, lambda, unreal-engine4

I'm modifying a code-base to get a struct (TheClipInfo) out of a Lambda so I can return one of it's properties (CurrentFrameCount).

I think I'm passing it by reference, but clearly I'm missing something.

Comments below show where I modified the code.

```
int32 UTimeSynthComponent::StopClipOffset(FTimeSynthClipHandle InClipHandle, ETimeSynthEventClipQuantization EventQuantization)
{
    Audio::EEventQuantization StopQuantization = GlobalQuantization;
    if (EventQuantization != ETimeSynthEventClipQuantization::Global)
    {
        int32 ClipQuantizationEnumIndex = (int32)EventQuantization;
        check(ClipQuantizationEnumIndex >= 1);
        StopQuantization = (Audio::EEventQuantization)(ClipQuantizationEnumIndex - 1);
    }

    FPlayingClipInfo TheClipInfo;  // I want the Lambda to put data here.

    SynthCommand([this, InClipHandle, StopQuantization, &TheClipInfo]  // The first Lambda
    {
        EventQuantizer.EnqueueEvent(StopQuantization,

            [this, InClipHandle, &TheClipInfo](uint32 NumFramesOffset)  // The Second Lambda
            {
                int32* PlayingClipIndex = ClipIdToClipIndexMap_AudioRenderThread.Find(InClipHandle.ClipId);
                if (PlayingClipIndex)
                {
                    // Grab the clip info
                    FPlayingClipInfo& PlayingClipInfo = PlayingClipsPool_AudioRenderThread[*PlayingClipIndex];  // The Struct I want to get out.

                    // Only do anything if the clip is not yet already fading
                    if (PlayingClipInfo.CurrentFrameCount < PlayingClipInfo.DurationFrames)
                    {
                        // Adjust the duration of the clip to "spoof" it's code which triggers a fade this render callback block.
                        PlayingClipInfo.DurationFrames = PlayingClipInfo.CurrentFrameCount + NumFramesOffset;
                    }
                    TheClipInfo = PlayingClipInfo;  // I think this should make a copy.
                }
            });
    });
    return TheClipInfo.CurrentFrameCount;  // This is always returning 0.
}
```

I'm assuming this is all happening in the same thread and in order (not some async callback like JavaScript).

My first attempt was with an int32, but that can't be passed by reference.  I really want just one value from it.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Snap!

```
EventQuantizer.EnqueueEvent
```

Adds the second lambda to an event queue.  So it is asynch.  Which is why it's not working as I'd like.

The simplest thing that could work is to copy the code out of the lambda and use it for the return.